# Java array Boolean error on array copy on one and not on the other why?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I created a method to do the horizontal mirror of a 4 by 4 array and another to rotate a 90 degree array to the right. The mirror method does not work but the method run function and I do not understand why the mirror method does not work.

```
public void miroirPiece(int pieceSel){
    if(pieceSel!=-1){
        boolean[][] tabTemp = new boolean[4][4];
        int k=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 3; j !=0; j--) {
                tabTemp[k][j]=tab[i][j];
                k++;
            }
            k=0;
        }
        rePositionPiece(tabTemp);
    }
}

public void rotate(int selectedPiece) {

    if (selectedPiece != -1) {
        int size = 4;
        boolean[][] tabTemp = new boolean[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                tabTemp[size - 1 - j][i] = tab[i][j];
            }
        }
        rePositionPiece(tabTemp);

    }
}
```

my data array:

```
true   true   true  true 
true   false  false false 
false  false  false false 
false  false  false false
```

this is what i have after the miror method

```
false  false  false  false 
false  false  false  false 
false  false  false  false 
false  false  false  false
```

this is the result expected:

```
true   true   true   true  
false  false  false  true   
false  false  false  false 
false  false  false  false
```

Comment: Please post only in English.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the traduction.

Comment: Can you post the expected and the actual output?

Comment: it seemed `rotate method` rotate array left 90 degree.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Are you asking about a compilation error?  Are you asking about a runtime exception?  Are you asking about the *behavior* of the code?

Comment: What does *"begin array: --------------------------------"* mean?

Comment: If you want us to help you, it is up to you to ask a clear Question (in English).  If your question is not clear enough for us to understand what you are really asking, then (obviously!) we won't be able to help you.

Comment: it's pretty simple :
the rotation method works
the mirror method disn't work
why the mirror method disn't work? do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the faulty section of the code:

```
for (int j = 3; j !=0; j--) {
    tabTemp[k][j] = tab[i][j];
    k++;
}
```

`i` is the row. For your purpose, you need to copy the front of each row to the end and vice versa.

So, the actual code should be: `tabTemp[i][k] = tab[i][j]`

Also, you're skipping the case when j is 0.

Do this:

```
for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
    tabTemp[i][k] = tab[i][j];
    k++;
}
```

Side note: you might want to make the variable names more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand your code. I think the mirror of this matrix is swaping the left part and right part of this matrix. Then the follow code maybe helpful.

```
public void miroirPiece(boolean[][]arr) {
     int left = 0, right = arr.length-1;
     while(left<right){
         for(int row = 0; row < arr.length;row++){
             boolean temp = arr[row][left];
             arr[row][left] = arr[row][right];
             arr[row][right] = temp;
         }
         left++;
         right--;
     }
     for(int row=0; row < arr.length;row++){
         for(int col = 0; col < arr[row].length;col++){
             System.out.print(arr[row][col]+" ");
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
}
```

and input arr[][]:

```
true   true   true  true 
true   false  false false 
false  false  false false 
false  false  false false
```

output:

```
true  true  true  true 
false false false true 
false false false false 
false false false false
```

Comment: Well the rotate code works fine and isn't the problem. it's just for the exemple of my code when workt. The problem is the miroirPiece methode.... it's not work. when i do : tabTemp[k][j]=tab[i][j]; it's not workt

Comment: vins20021 my code achieve the function of yours `miroirPiece method` rather than 'rotate' . And your `miroirPiece` assign value only for tabTemp[0][3] tabTemp[1][2] tabTemp[2][1]. You can debug it.